# Another integral representation of Catalan's Constant?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, catalans-constant

The integral in question:
$$I=\int_{0}^{1} {\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}dx.$$

So I have a solution and it's rather straightforward, but I don't much like it. I'm not sure how to tackle this integral head-on, as you'll see, and I was wondering if anyone had another way of arriving at the result.

My Solution:

Let

$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} {\ln{(\sin{(x)}+a)}}\hspace{1pt}dx.$$

Then

$$I'(a)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} {\frac{1}{\sin{(x)}+a}}dx=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\arctan{\left(\frac{a-1}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)}.$$

To show this one can apply the Weierstrass Substitution and complete the square in the denominator.

Now consider the following

$$\int_{0}^{1} {\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\arctan{\left(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)}}dx=I(1)-I(0).$$

Noticing the famous result $I(0)=-{\pi}\ln(2)/2$ (check [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931388/integration-of-ln-sin-x-from-0-to-frac-pi2by-duis) for more details) we have

$$I=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{(2)}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} {\ln{(\sin{(x)}+1)}}\hspace{1pt}dx.$$

Using

$$\sin{(x)}+1=2\sin{\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}\cos{\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)}$$

we arrive at the following
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{(2)}+2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} {\ln{(\cos{(x)})}}\hspace{1pt}dx$$

and now by [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199094/evaluating-int-0-large-frac-pi4-log-left-cos-x-right-mathrmdx) we have $I=C$, where $C$ is Catalan's Constant.

If you have seen this integral before please let me know where and again if you have a different solution that would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Essentially equivalent to identities $(7)$ and $(8)$ [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2325473_Representations_of_Catalan's_Constant) if you retrace your steps. But cool nonetheless, +1.

Comment: @K.defaoite I suppose so, though I really want to approach the integral all on its own, as if you had seen it out on its own and had no idea of the connection with Catalan's Constant. Of course, thank you for the upvote.

Comment: @Gonçalo Surprisingly no, in fact, the integral of that from 0 to 1 is $\frac{{\pi}^2}{16}$. This isn't too hard to see as that integral actually has a nice antiderivative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} {\frac{\tan^{-1}\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}dx
=& \int_{0}^{1} {\frac{\tanh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\overset{y=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}} }{dx}\\
=&\ 2\int_0^1\frac{\tanh y}{1+y^2}\overset{y\to \frac{1-y}{1+y} }{dy}= -\int_0^1 \frac{\ln y}{1+y^2}dy=C
\end{align}

Comment: Very nice, so cool to have such a legend respond. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AlejandroJimenezTellado - it’s a pleasure

Answer (score 7):

Using the identity $\arctan(iz)=i\tanh^{-1}(z)$, we may rewrite the integral as
$$
I=\int_{0}^{1} {\frac{\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\,dx. \tag{1}
$$
Substituting $x$ with $\text{sech}\,u$, we may rewrite $(1)$ as
\begin{align}
I&=\int_{\infty}^{0} \frac{\tanh^{-1}\left(\tanh(u/2)\right)}{\tanh u}\,(-\tanh u\,\text{sech}\,u)\,du \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u}{\cosh u}\,du, \tag{2}
\end{align}
which is integral (5) in the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2325473_Representations_of_Catalan%27s_Constant) linked by @K.defaoite.